# video with object-fit cover spilling out of container

Tags: html, css, video

I am building a website that has a full screen splash video at the top,
To make the video look good on all screens I use object-fit cover.

As you can see in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rHyECCvyLmcoBaG0y1rp?p=preview) the video element spills out of its container over the next element.
To see this behaviour, scale the preview window down to a very narrow letterbox format, then look at the bottom edge of the video element, you'll notice the video continues where the container stopped.

How can I constrain the video to it's container or hide the overflow?

```
<body>
<div class="splash-container">

  <h1 class="splash-title underline">title</h1>

  <div class="splash-scroll-indicator">
    <a scrollTo class="underline" href="#intro">proceed</a>
    <br><i class="icofont icofont-curved-down"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="splash-overlay"></div>

  <video class="video-src" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="//s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/evanzummeren.com/rijksmuseum.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    video tag is not supported in this browser
  </video>
</div>
<div class="container" id="intro">
  <div class="row text-center intro">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sem magna, tincidunt fermentum quam in,<br> imperdiet varius quam. Nulla facilisi. Integer efficitur congue semper. Nunc a mauris sed tortor aliquam porttitor. Sed varius purus et magna vulputate facilisis. In a feugiat nisi. Sed venenatis libero sed lectus fringilla, vitae aliquet sapien semper. Mauris nisl sapien, dictum ac laoreet eu, vestibulum vitae ante. Nam maximus laoreet lectus vitae pretium. Integer eu orci tincidunt, sagittis leo congue,<br> auctor nisi. Suspendisse ut tortor ac mi varius rutrum eu ut orci. Aenean imperdiet lectus ante.<br>
      <br><br>Nullam feugiat vel nibh sed aliquet. Fusce sit amet eros id mauris consectetur interdum. <br>Curabitur pretium lectus non nisl pretium facilisis. Pellentesque id ultrices est. Mauris non lacinia elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Microsoft Edge dev site has an up-vote option where you can vote for `object-fit` for `video` elements.  Here is the link: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `splash-container`.

Comment: ugh Tom thank you, I had already tried that with no succes. but now I noticed my cached css file soo yep.. I'm an idiot